# Как из ViewModel UserControl'a изменить свойство в ViewModel главного окна

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Вопрос простой, но распишу его подробно.

---

Недавно начал попытки создавать приложение WPF с применением MVVM, и у меня возник вопрос, который не даёт мне продвигаться в разработке далее. Суть такова: есть главное окно, к нему сделан MainWindowViewModel, в котором есть св-во CurrentVM,
есть 2 UserControla и 2 ViewModel'a для них, в xaml разметке ContentPresenter главного окна привязан к св-ву CurrentVM из ViewModel.
    `

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserControl1ViewModel}">
        <view:UserControl1/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserControl2ViewModel}">
        <view:UserControl2/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContentVM}"/>`.
```

Это всё сделано для попытки менять содержимое в одном окне. Изначально в окно подставляется содержимое UserControl1 в конструкторе MainWindowViewModel:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CurrentContentVM = new UserControl1();
    }
```

При запуске мы на UserControl1.
В этом контроле есть кнопка - перейти на следующий контрол - UserControl2.

```
<Button Content="Перейти на следующее окно." Command="{Binding Go_Clicked}" FontSize="40" Margin="100 150 100 150"/>
```

По нажатию на кнопку должны подставить в содержимое главного окна второй контрол. Как это сделать, находяcь в viewModel UserControl1? Ведь после нажатия на эту кнопку: мы попадаем в команду в классе UserControl1ViewModel:

```
private RelayCommand go_Clicked;
    public RelayCommand Go_Clicked
    {
        get
        {
            return go_Clicked ??
                (go_Clicked = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    //здесь должна быть логика, как поменять св-во CurrentVM
                    //в классе MainWindowViewModel на new UserControl2();

                }));
        }
    }
```

Использую только стандартные средства C# без подключения MVVM Light, Fody и прочего. Обьясните, пожалуйста, как взаимодейстовать из ViewModel контролла на св-во в ViewModel главного окна? Чем больше информации, тем лучше, т.к я новичек.
Это всё сделано для попытки после успешной авторизации из некого UserControlla подменить содержимое окна приложения на содержимое с функционалом Usera. 
Далее уже не по теме:

---

Совсем не понимаю таких вещей, как например, если я даже открою UserControl2, как из него смогу попасть обратно на UserControl1? Или даже как брать информацию из диалогового окна, которое открывается, с применением MVVM. Потому что пытался делать по MVVM, даже не смог установить св-во DialogResult окна из ViewModel диалогового окна.

Comment: `new UserControl1(this);`, где `this` - это `MainWindowViewModel`. В самом же `UserControl1` вы принимаете эту ссылку на главную VM через конструктор, ну а дальше делаете что вашей душе угодно в главной VM.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую. А это не  потянет за собой цепочку ссылок? В моём проекте В главном окне лежат страницы Pages, и в   странице авторизации в зависимости от введёных данных в её ViewModel должно выполняться то, что поменяет содержимое главного окна на окно Usera. То есть уже много слоёв так сказать, глубоко придётся передавать, наверное, указатели this.

Comment: Главное слои не перепутайте (VM/M/V), а остальное, ну что тут такого, если у вас будет ссылка на главную VM в 10-ти других VM? Как по мне это вполне простой и надежный вариант решения данной задачи.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, я попробовал так
`public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
 
        public UserControl1(MainWindowViewModel obj)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            obj.CurrentContentVM = new UserControl2();

        }
    }` , по идее должно показаться UserControl2, но показывает первый. Кстати, это мы можем изменять содержимое из UserControl1.xaml.cs а не из его ViewModel, как изменять это свойство из UserControl1ViewModel?

Comment: Оу, простите, я не правильно немного вам сказал. Не `UserControl1`, а `UserControl1ViewModel`. View часть вы не как не трогаете, она чисто за представление отвечает и все, а вот VM слои вы и можете соединить передачей ссылки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте в ваших моделях представлений событие, на которое будет реагировать ваша главная модель представлений. Тоесть, вы нажимаете на кнопку, которая привязана к функции модели представлений для контрола. В этой функции вызывайте событие, на котороае в свою очередь подписана главная модель представления. В моделе представления уже вызываете код, который вам нужен.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, более подробно? Ловить событие должен Класс  MainWindowViewModel, в котором есть свойство CurrentVM, принимающее UserControl1 или UserControl2.  Этот класс никак не связан с UserControl1ViewModel, в котором, видимо, нужно генерировать событие. Создавать событие нужно через EventHandler? А как ловить в другом классе?

Comment: В вашем коде MainWindowViewModel содержит ссылку на элемент интерфейса?  Это противоречит принципам MVVM патерна. Свойство CurrentContentVM должно содержать ссылку на UserControlViewModel  но не как на сам контрол...

Comment: Спасибо, переделал присвоение к св-ву CurrentVM = UserControlViewModel1(this); теперь там в UserControl1ViewModel могу изменять CurrentVM главного окна. Это пока что помогло чуть продвинуться

Comment: Сейчас кину ссылку на тестовый проект...

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlSP672c0D-fqZIqTt1crhrmkYbJng

Comment: В теории ваша UserControlViewModel ничего не должна знать о MainViewModel, и тем более управлять MainViewModel.

Comment: Спасибо большое, пример несложный, плюс как я понял тут всё по правилам MVVM, думал насчёт событий, но не знал как их отлавливать и создавать. Видимо нужно было доработать мой класс RelayCommand, добавив делегат и EventHandler.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если что - обращайтесь :)

Comment: @AlexanderKraft Не могли бы вы сбросить ссылку на проект ещё раз?

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам такой примерчик
[image: пример работы]
Работа с вьюшками организована через спец.класс `AppController`.

Начнем с абстракций

```
//типы вьюшек
public enum CurrentViewTypes
{
    Start,
    Edit,
}

public interface IAppController
{
    //контекст данных приложения
    IDataContext DataContext { get; }
    //вьюмодель гл.окна
    IMainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel { get; }
    //отображение нужной вьюшки
    void ChangeCurrentView(CurrentViewTypes viewType);
    //для передачи данных между вьюмоделями
    object ViewModelBag { get; set; }
    //запрос к пользователю на согласие
    Task<bool> IsMessageYesNoResult(string message);
}

public interface IMainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //отображаемая вьюха
    object CurrentView { get; set; }
    //отображаемое сообщение
    object MessageView { get; set; }
}
```

В окне программы такой XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MessageView}"/>
</Grid>
```

Вьюмодель окна

```
class MainWindowViewModel : IMainWindowViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение вьюшек
    /// </summary>
    private object _CurrentView;
    public object CurrentView
    {
        get => _CurrentView;
        set
        {
            _CurrentView = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentView)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение вьюшки-сообщения
    /// </summary>
    private object _MessageView;
    public object MessageView
    {
        get => _MessageView;
        set
        {
            _MessageView = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MessageView)));
        }
    }
}
```

Реализация контроллера

```
class AppController : IAppController
{
    //ctor
    public AppController(IMainWindowViewModel mainWindowVM)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel = mainWindowVM ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainWindowVM));

        //подключаем тестовый источник данных
        DataContext = new TestDataContext();
    }

    public IDataContext DataContext { get; }
    public IMainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel { get; }
    public object ViewModelBag { get; set; }

    public void ChangeCurrentView(CurrentViewTypes viewType)
    {
        switch (viewType)
        {
            case CurrentViewTypes.Start:
                IStartViewModel sVM = new StartViewModel(this);
                StartView sV = new StartView();
                //привязка
                sV.DataContext = sVM;
                //отображение
                MainWindowViewModel.CurrentView = sV;
                break;
            case CurrentViewTypes.Edit:
                IEditViewModel eVM = new EditViewModel(this);
                EditView eV = new EditView();
                //привязка
                eV.DataContext = eVM;
                //отображение
                MainWindowViewModel.CurrentView = eV;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(viewType));
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsMessageYesNoResult(string message)
    {
        //создаем и отображаем сообщение пользователю
        var yN = new YesNoMessage();
        yN.Text = message;
        MainWindowViewModel.MessageView = yN;

        //получаем результат и убираем сообщение
        bool result = await yN.GetResult();
        MainWindowViewModel.MessageView = null;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Чтоб задействовать контроллер:

1) удалим в App.xaml `StartupUri="..."`

2) в App.xaml.cs напишем следующее

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static IAppController _controller;

    //ctor
    public App()
    {
        //вьюмодель окна программы
        IMainWindowViewModel mainVM = new MainWindowViewModel();
        //контроллер
        _controller = new AppController(mainVM);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //подписка на возникновение неперехваченных исключений
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        //сообщения об ошибках будем писать в файл (его можно будет найти в папке с exe)
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(File.CreateText("log.txt")));
        Trace.AutoFlush = true;

        //окно программы
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        //привязка к окну её вьюмодели
        mainWindow.DataContext = _controller.MainWindowViewModel;
        //отображаем окно
        mainWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        mainWindow.Title = "Пример простого шаблона программы";
        mainWindow.Show();

        //отображение начальной вьюшки
        _controller.ChangeCurrentView(CurrentViewTypes.Start);
    }

    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //пишем в лог все неперехваченные ошибки
        Trace.WriteLine((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message);
    }
}
```

Вот пример стартовой вьюмодели со списком людей

```
public class StartViewModel : IStartViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly IAppController _appController;

    //ctor
    public StartViewModel(IAppController appController)
    {
        _appController = appController ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appController));

        //команды
        EditCommand = new RelayCommand(OnEdit, CanEdit);
        DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(OnDelete, CanDelete);
        CreateCommand = new RelayCommand(OnCreate, CanCreate);

        //загружаем из БД людей
        LoadPeople();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Список для ListView
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выбранный в ListView чел.
    /// </summary>
    private Person _SelectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get => _SelectedPerson;
        set
        {
            _SelectedPerson = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedPerson)));
            //перепроверка возможности выполнения команд
            (EditCommand as RelayCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            (DeleteCommand as RelayCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка списка Людей
    /// </summary>
    private async void LoadPeople()
    {
        try
        {
            //получаем людей из БД
            var people = await _appController.DataContext.GetPeopleAsync();
            People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(people);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"Загрузка списка людей: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Изменить
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand EditCommand { get; }
    private bool CanEdit()
    {
        return SelectedPerson != null;
    }
    private void OnEdit()
    {
        //передаем ссылку на выбранного чела
        _appController.ViewModelBag = SelectedPerson;
        //переходим к вьюшке редактирования чела
        _appController.ChangeCurrentView(CurrentViewTypes.Edit);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Удалить
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }
    private bool CanDelete()
    {
        return SelectedPerson != null;
    }
    private async void OnDelete()
    {
        string message = $"Вы согласны удалить: {SelectedPerson.FirstName} {SelectedPerson.LastName}?";
        //отображем вьюшку-сообщение и ждем выбор пользователя
        if (await _appController.IsMessageYesNoResult(message))
        {
            try
            {
                await _appController.DataContext.RemovePerson(SelectedPerson.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"Удаление чела id={SelectedPerson.Id} вызвало ошибку: {ex.Message}");
            }

            //удаляем из отображаемого списка
            People.Remove(SelectedPerson);
            SelectedPerson = null;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Создать
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand CreateCommand { get; }
    private bool CanCreate()
    {
        return true;
    }
    private void OnCreate()
    {
        //создаем ссылку на нового чела
        _appController.ViewModelBag = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "<?>",
            LastName = "<?>",
            Birthdate = DateTime.Parse("01.01.1980")
        };
        //переходим к редактированию чела
        _appController.ChangeCurrentView(CurrentViewTypes.Edit);
    }
}
```

А это вьюмодель редактирования человека

```
public class EditViewModel : IEditViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly IAppController _appController;

    //ctor
    public EditViewModel(IAppController appController)
    {
        _appController = appController ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appController));

        //команды
        BackCommand = new RelayCommand(OnBack, CanBack);
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSave, CanSave);

        //получаем редактируемый экземпляр Person
        if (_appController.ViewModelBag == null
            || (CurrentPerson = (_appController.ViewModelBag as Person)) == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(_appController.ViewModelBag));
        }
        else
        {
            _appController.ViewModelBag = null;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Редактируемый чел
    /// </summary>
    private Person _СurrentPerson;
    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get => _СurrentPerson;
        set
        {
            _СurrentPerson = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentPerson)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Назад
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand BackCommand { get; }
    private bool CanBack()
    {
        return true;
    }
    private void OnBack()
    {
        _appController.ChangeCurrentView(CurrentViewTypes.Start);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Сохранить
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }
    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return true;
    }
    private async void OnSave()
    {
        try
        {
            //сохраняем в БД
            await _appController.DataContext.SavePersonAsync(CurrentPerson);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"Ошибка сохранения чела: {ex.Message}");
        }

        //возвращаемся назад
        _appController.ChangeCurrentView(CurrentViewTypes.Start);
    }
}
```

Весь пример лежит [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/ExNavigationWpf).

Comment: `Trace.WriteLine($"Ошибка сохранения чела: {ex.Message}");` Поставлю плюс за это ：D

Comment: @LLENN спасибо, да, эта строчка у меня особенно удалась..:)

Comment: Спасибо юольшое, гифка красивая, но код сложный) Постараюсь что-нибудь понять.. В любом случае, чем больше материала - тем лучше.

Comment: @Dmitry пожалуйста. Чтоб разобраться с кодом, его нужно запускать, ставить точки останова, пробовать что-либо менять, а для этого нужно склонировать проект с гитхаба по ссылке, которую я дал. Желаю удачи.